# Best practise for passing or not passing ID to POST action via REST Web Api?

Tags: rest, post, request, response, asp.net-web-api

I have a POST action which creates a record in database. I was wondering which of the following options is better?

1. Pass the ID as a parameter to POST, which meant we need to initialise the parameter with a GUID value. Therefore there is no response for POST except the status code
2. Do not pass the ID to POST action and let it be created in database (e.g IDENTITY) and then return it in the response along with status code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd choose option 2. Whilst there are some good arguments for 1, consider these:

1. As you implied, all traditional DBs allow primary key generation (usually by auto-incrementing) - i.e. you get it for free
2. It is not the caller's responsibility to invent suitable IDs for your database
3. By publicising it, you're committing internal details to your external API, which is never good. What if you wanted to completely re-think your ID schema later on (e.g. reserved ID ranges)?
4. Option 1 has too many extra error conditions and paths that would need testing (clashing IDs etc), time better spent on the API itself.